# Al crear preferencia con envío, el usuario puede seleccionar otras direcciones de envío en el checkout de MercadoPago

Tags: mercadopago

Creando la preferencia siguiente (siguiendo las instrucciones de https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/es/solutions/payments/basic-checkout/use-mercadoenvios/) el usuario puede seleccionar otra dirección de envío en el checkout, como puedo evitar eso?

Necesito que al enviar una preferencia con los campos "shipments" el usuario no pueda seleccionar otra dirección, puesto que ya estoy cobrando el valor de envío indicado por el calculador según (https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/es/related/shipping-calculator/) y si el usuario selecciona otra dirección (con otro CP) el costo de envío pude ser mayor!

Gracias por la ayuda!

**Preferencia**

```
{
  "external_reference":"QLU3087",
  "items":[
    {
      "id":"Order Number: QLU3087 - Order ID: 113",
      "title":"Sample store - QLU3087",
      "description":"Sample store",
      "quantity":1,
      "unit_price":899.11,
      "currency_id":"ARS",
      "picture_url":"http:\/\/www.domain.com\/vendor_0x90.gif"
    }
  ],
  "payer":{
    "name":"Gisa",
    "surname":"Mar",
    "email":"wererdew@erereswd.com"
  },
  "back_urls":{
    "success":"http:\/\/www.domain.com\/statusok.html",
    "failure":"http:\/\/www.domain.com\/statusfail.html",
    "pending":"http:\/\/www.domain.com\/statuspending.html"
  },
  "payment_methods":{
    "excluded_payment_types":[]
  },
  "notification_url":"http:\/\/www.domain.com\/ipn_notification.html",
  "auto_return":"approved",
  "shipments":{
    "mode":"me2",
    "dimensions":"14x14x14,1500",
    "local_pickup":false,
    "free_methods":[
      {
        "id":73328
      }
    ],
    "receiver_address":{
      "zip_code":1605
    },
    "default_shipping_method":73328,
    "zip_code":1605
  }
}
```